# Including HTML markup in a code example

Tags: support, markdown

I'm sorry if this question has come up before, but numerous searches proved fruitless.

How do I include a block of HTML markup in a code snippet within a post here, without the post editor trying to render it? I have a PHP/HTML/CSS question and can't for the life of me figure out how to include the relevant code.

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe.  Regardless, select the text you're trying to paste in, then click the `{}` button in the toolbar, it's to the right of the quote tool and the left of the picture tool.  This will mark the text as code by automatically indenting it four spaces.  For more help, click the big fat question mark button on the right side of the toolbar.

Comment: Wow, I know for a fact I tried that at least once to no avail. Could it have had something to do with the fact that the first line of each snipped was *** filename.php ***, reflecting the name of the file being displayed?  Thanks!

Comment: Code formatting can act a bit funny if there's only one newline between it and the preceding line.

Answer (score 1):

Indent by four spaces, like with any other code snippet.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title for your page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if I use `<pre></pre>`?